# Need SQL to update table with data from another table IF numbers match

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this function below that is letting user choose excel file and it imports the data into a table(MyTable). Its just a single column excel file. The table it imports into contains 2 columns(F1,F2).

I need the DoCmd.RunSQL command to get the following info into that 2nd column.

MyTable.F1 is the OEM part number
I need to take that number and compare it to 2 columns (OEMPartNumer, OEMSub) in a (JDSubs) table i have setup
If it finds a match i need it to compare those 2 matches from (JDSubs) table and try to find it in (AMI) table in column (OEMItem)
If it finds that match i need to return value from column (Item) from table (AMI) and insert it into (MyTable) column (F2)

Table contents example

```
MyTable
----------------
F1       | F2
AR77530  | 
AR12345  |

JDSubs
---------------------------
OEMPartNumer    | OEMSub
AR65123         | AR77530
AR12345         | AR56242

AMI
---------------------------
Item            | OEMItem
AMAR77530       | AR77530
AMAR56242       | AR12345
```

So the number being imported from the excel file could be one of 2 numbers(sometimes there is no sub number)

I just need to match up my companies part number (AMI) to the OEM number

Here is the function i am importing the worksheet with into MyTable
I just need to get F2 column filled with matching AMI numbers and export back out

```vb
 Sub Import()
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim CustomerFile As String
    Dim LUser As String

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select your OEM part number file."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xlsx"
    .Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & LUser & "\Desktop"
    If .Show = True Then
          'Loop through each file selected and add it to the list box.
          For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
             CustomerFile = varFile
          Next
    End If
    End With
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable", CustomerFile, False, "sheet1!A:A"
    DoCmd.RunSQL ?????


    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Also, I have a form setup so the user can look up one number at a time. Here is the function for it. I just need to have an automated process for it

```vb
Function fnSearchAndPopulate() As Boolean
Dim d As DAO.Database, r As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
Set d = CurrentDb
If Me.txtEnterNumber.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Number", , "Error"
    Exit Function
End If
strSQL = " SELECT * FROM JDSubs Inner Join AMI on " & _
         " AMI.OEMItem=JDSubs.OEMPartNumber WHERE " & _
         " JDSubs.OEMPartNumber= '" & txtEnterNumber.Value & "' or " & _
         " JDSubs.OEMSub= '" & txtEnterNumber.Value & "
Debug.Print strSQL
Set r = d.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If r.EOF Then
   MsgBox "OEM # " & Me.txtEnterNumber & " does not exist!", , "No AMI #"
  Set d = Nothing
  Exit Function
End If
'get here if there is a record
r.MoveFirst
'populate whatever textboxes
Me.txtAMINumber = r!Item
Me.txtDescription = r!Description
Me.txtOEMsubnumber = r!OEMSub

Set d = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with 2 update queries with different joins.  Also, I recommend using Currentdb.Execute instead of DoCmd.Runsql because Execute doesn't throw any warning pop up boxes:

```
Currentdb.Execute 
    "UPDATE 
    (MyTable INNER JOIN JDSubs ON MyTable.F1 = JDSubs.OEMPartNumber) 
    INNER JOIN AMI ON JDSubs.OEMPartNumber = AMI.OEMItem 
    SET MyTable.F2 = [AMI].[Item];"

Currentdb.Execute
    "UPDATE 
    (MyTable INNER JOIN JDSubs ON MyTable.F1 = JDSubs.OEMSub) 
    INNER JOIN AMI ON JDSubs.OEMSub = AMI.OEMItem
    SET MyTable.F2 = [AMI].[Item];"
```

Does this work?

Comment: It works fine if the number i search is (OEMPartNumer) BUT (OEMSub) is not working. It just displays blank

Comment: its because the (OEMSub) is not in AMI.OEMItem. The OEMSub needs to get the OEMPartNumber and Match it to AMI.OEMItem. How is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  I made a mock db to test these queries. When both are run, MyTable.F2 is populated with `AMAR77520` (1st row) and `AMAR56242` (2nd row). Should it say something else?

Comment: Not sure why its not working on the OEMSub. Here is and example of the one that is left blank. AR26840 is the OEMPartNumber, RE29610 is the OEMSub. AR2640 is the OEMItem and AMAR2640 is the Item (Item is what should be returned to F2). I think the first update is putting the number in F2 and since then OEMSub doesnt match to the OEMItem its setting F2 to blank. Can you put something in to say if the value is there, dont change?

Comment: Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: In your example, what is MyTable.F1?

Comment: That is where the user imports the spreadsheet. That is the OEM part number that need to be matched to OEMpartnumber and OEMSub

Comment: When you say "since then OEMSub doesnt match to the OEMItem its setting F2 to blank", it's not doing that. If it doesn't find a record, it's just skipped completely (it's an inner join, not a left join).  You can test this if you want by just using 1 of the 2 updates at a time and looking at the results.