# Need SQL to update table with data from another table (adding another column to one already done)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I recently asked this question below
[Need SQL to update table with data from another table IF numbers match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467388/need-sql-to-update-table-with-data-from-another-table-if-numbers-match)

I have it working but trying to add something else now.

I wanted to bring another column into my table. (Description)

```
d.Execute "UPDATE (MyTable 
            INNER JOIN JDSubs ON MyTable.F1 = JDSubs.OEMPartNumber)
            INNER JOIN AMIPartNumbers ON JDSubs.OEMPartNumber = AMIPartNumbers.OEMItem 
           SET MyTable.F2 = [AMIPartNumbers].[Item];"

d.Execute "UPDATE (MyTable 
            INNER JOIN JDSubs ON MyTable.F1 = JDSubs.OEMsubnumber)
            INNER JOIN AMIPartNumbers ON JDSubs.OEMsubnumber = AMIPartNumbers.OEMItem 
           SET MyTable.F2 = [AMIPartNumbers].[Item];"
```

That is the code i have now that brings back my Item number based on OEMPartNumber and OEMSub. Now i would like to bring back description too.

```
MyTable
----------------
F1       | F2      | F3
AR77530  |         | 
AR12345  |         |

JDSubs
---------------------------
OEMPartNumer    | OEMSub
AR65123         | AR77530
AR12345         | AR56242

AMI
---------------------------
Item            | OEMItem   | Description
AMAR77530       | AR77530   | Axle
AMAR56242       | AR12345   | Spindle
```

So now i would like to add the (Description) from AMI table and put in MyTable.F3

Comment: Just adding: MyTable.F3 = AMIPartNumbers.Description doesn't work?

Comment: like this? SET MyTable.F2 = [AMIPartNumbers].[Item] MyTable.F3 = [AMIPartNumbers].[Description];"

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work by adding what you suggested. Can you add it to what i have above to make sure im adding it right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET MyTable.F2 = [AMIPartNumbers].[Item], MyTable.F3 = [AMIPartNumbers].Description
```

You can set multiple variables in a single update statement. Assuming AMIPartNumbers is the same table as AMI